# picture to the left and text in center

Tags: android, layout

I want the little icon in my custom button to be aligned to the left and both textviews to be centered in the relativeview. How can i do that?
As you can se i try to center the text horizontal and i try to align the icon to the left but it doesn't work.

```
 <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/Imagesbtn"
            android:background="@drawable/MainButtonLayout"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IconImage"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_pictureblack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/largeTextImages"
                android:text="Images"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IconImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/smallTextImages"
                android:text="Acces images"
                android:layout_below="@id/largeTextImages"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

This is MainButtonLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <!--<stroke android:width="400dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />-->
    <corners android:radius="4dip"/>
   <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip"  android:bottom="0dip" />

    </shape>
```

[image]

I want the text to be aligned in the middle so that the center of the text is right on the red line and i want all the icons to be centered on the yellow line. Do you get it?:)
Here is what i get:
[image]

Comment: Is this your whole layout file code ?

Comment: noo, there is a couple of rows in the tablerow and there is a relativelayout outside of it

Comment: @DanielGustafsson please change the drawable file name to mainbuttonlayout as drawables don't allow capital letters. I tried your code and it works fine

Comment: Do you want both text center aligned to image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan text to be horizontally center aligned try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Imagesbtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbuttonlayout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IconImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/largeTextImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IconImage"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Images"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallTextImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/largeTextImages"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IconImage"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Acces images"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Example

[image]

EDIT1

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IconImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/largeTextImages"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/largeTextImages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Images"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallTextImages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/largeTextImages"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Acces images"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: the icon is where i want it but i want the text to be centered in the relativelayout to that it is in the middle of your example.

Comment: Also you can remove             android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/largeTextImages"
to set icon to the right

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `TableRow` from your code. If you have not used `TableLayout` then there is no need of `TableRow` also.

Try out below code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Imagesbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbuttonlayout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IconImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/largeTextImages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IconImage"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Images"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smallTextImages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/largeTextImages"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IconImage"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Acces images"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Im using tablelayout i just cut it out from my example cause it was so much code.